# Manifest/Class-Path in jar file not successfully setting a directory on the CLASSPATH for log4j2.xml

Tags: java, ant, log4j, manifest, log4j2

I've successfully written a small Java program that finds and uses my log4j2.xml file when run from NetBeans. I'm now trying to create a jar file that contains my other jars, so I can run it on the command line. I built the jar file with Ant and use a "Manifest" inside of my jar target.

After the build, I do 'java -jar BimbleParser.jar', and all of the jars files that I placed in the Manifest 'Class-Path' are found, and the program runs correctly. Except that it does not log per the log4j2.xml file ( to a .log file ). When I set things up to force an error, I get a few 'ERROR's logged to the command line, I believe a default behavior of log4j2, indicating that it has not found the log4j2.xml file.

I'm quite positive that the directory containing log4j2.xml is not being found on the CLASSPATH as set in the manifest in the 'jar' target of my build file.

Here's the ant task with the manifest in it:

```
   <target name="jar" description="Create jar file" depends="junit">
    <jar destfile="${project.name}.jar" duplicate="add" basedir="${classes_dir}"       filesetmanifest="skip" >
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Build-Date" value="${TODAY} ${TSTAMP}"/>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.mumble.parsers.Bumble.BumbleParser"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="./CCom/config ./CCom/lib/CComCommons.jar ./CCom/lib/commons-configuration.jar ./CCom/lib/commons-lang.jar ./CCom/lib/log4j-api.jar ./CCom/lib/log4j-core.jar ./CCom/lib/commons-logging.jar ./CCom/lib/commons.lang3.jar"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

The log4j2.xml is located in the first classpath entry, as './CCom/config' and all of the other jar files are found and used by my program. What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps there are alternate solutions for making the log4j2.xml file visible via the classpath in this 'java -jar BimbleParser.jar' scenario?

Thanks for your help

Comment: try removing log4j2-api.jar from your Class-Path and see if it works

Comment: That doesn't help - NoClassDefFoundError. That jar file contains 'LogManager', more or less the 'root' class of all of that logging functionality.

Comment: Try using `/CCom/config` rather than `./CCom/Config` in the `Class-Path` attribute of your Manifest

Comment: That makes it a different path - a path relative to the root of the drive. The way I have it, it's a relative path based off where ever 'java -jar BimbleParser.jar' is run from.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are still bugs in automatic configuration. As a workaround try using this (after correcting path to your log2j.xml file):

```
URI configuration = MyClass.class.getResource("/<path>/log4j2.xml").toURI();
Configurator.initialize("config", null, configuration);
```

Based on example: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/log4j2/trunk/core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/FormatterLoggerManualExample.java